# vaadin. Do smth when client refresh page

Tags: javascript, vaadin, page-refresh

I start use vaadin.
I need to run my javascript after reloading page.

How can i do something when client refresh page?
Or how to catch "refresh page" event in vaadin?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please define what you consider a refresh and when is that happening

Comment: when user click refresh/update/reload page in browther
 I need to run my javascript after reloading page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably overriding paint method can help:

```
public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void init() {
    final Window mainWindow = new Window("Hello world app");

    SomeComponent hl = new SomeComponent();

    hl.addComponent(new Label("Hello world"));

    mainWindow.addComponent(hl);

    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}

public class SomeComponent extends HorizontalLayout {
   @Override
  public void paint(PaintTarget target) throws PaintException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paint(target);

    getWindow().executeJavaScript("alert('paint invoked')");
  }
}
```